# What is the current Android SDK support? - Expo

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo

I can not find the Expo support for Android SDKs. Android 4.4 is no longer supported since Expo SDK v31.0.0 version [Here](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v31-0-0-is-now-available-cad6d0463f49). Since Expo v31 now is 6.0

Where can i find more information about Android SDK support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see it in the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/introduction/why-not-expo/):

> The minimum supported OS versions are Android 5+ and iOS 10+
>
> If you need to support older versions, you will not be able to use the managed workflow.

[Android 5.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms#5.0) is Lollipop, API 21.